# Anybody knows why I get the 'Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions'?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am currently studying on how to use the firebase and I cant figure out a way to only a user update, delete or read only the images(collections) added by them.

This is my firestore structures:
[image]

and this is the security rules Im using:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    function authed(){
        return request.auth != null
    }
    function matchesUser(){
        return request.auth.uid == data.userId
    }
    
    allow read: if authed() && matchesUser(resource.data)
    allow create: if authed() && matchesUser(request.resource.data)
    }
}
```

When I try get the data/read the images(collection), I get the `Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`

and this is the code where I try to read the data from the firestore

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {projectFirestore} from '../firebase/firebase'
import {useAuth} from '../contexts/AuthContext'

const useFirestore = (collection) => {
    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([])
    const {currentUser} = useAuth()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = projectFirestore.collection(collection)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .where("userId", "==", currentUser.uid)
        .onSnapshot((snap) => {
            let documents = []
            snap.forEach(doc => {
                documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
            })
            setDocs(documents)
        })
        return () => unsub()
    }, [collection, currentUser])

    return {docs}
}

export default useFirestore
```

and this is the code where I try for a user to upload a file to firebase:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp} from '../firebase/firebase'
import {useAuth} from '../contexts/AuthContext'

const useStorage = (file) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null)

    const {currentUser} = useAuth()

    useEffect(() => {
        // references
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name)
        const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images')

        storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {
            let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
            setProgress(percentage)
        }, (err) => {
            setError(err)
        }, async () => {
            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL()
            const createdAt = timestamp();
            collectionRef.add({
                url,
                userId: currentUser.uid, 
                createdAt
            })
            setUrl(url)
        })
    }, [file])

    return { progress, error, url }
}

export default useStorage
```

Comment: Your `matchesUser()` function appears to be missing the `data` parameter? `function matchesUser(data){ return request.auth.uid == data.userId }`

Comment: That seems like an answer @samthecodingman. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, yeah it works. Now I see why it didnt work at first.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen only so much I can be bothered to type out on my phone on the bus without getting motion sick. The intention was to come back to it later on my PC haha. It is now properly hydrated as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Sam! And kudos for being able to type on a bus at all 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `matchesUser()` function you have created in your security rules, you pass in a parameter that contains the document's data. However where you defined the function, this parameter is not defined - leading to a syntax error where you try to read the `userId` property of an undefined object.

It should be defined as:

```js
function matchesUser(data) {
  return request.auth.uid == data.userId
}
```

The reason you get the `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions` error is because all syntax errors in security rules are treated as `false` (i.e. deny access). To discover typos like this in the future, you can make use of the [Security Rules Playground](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/rules) or test your rules using the [Security Rules Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator).

Comment: Yes, it works just like you said before. Silly me, i shouldve been more careful though. I understood after you just told me that I miss `data` parameter hahaha. Thank you so much though, I really appreciated it.